# Mask with numpy isin

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to make a mask with numpy array. I've found a function, but it doesn't make what I want. Here is the code example:

```
np.isin([1,2,3,4,5,8,6,1,1],[1,2,3,5,1])
```

This code returns this:

```
array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

But I want the same output except the last value of the output array to be False. Because I need exact mask of the sequence (`[1,2,3,5,1]`) in this order and no longer than its length.

Comment: `isin` is a set like test.  Each `1` on the left array is found on the right; values on the right are not used up by being matched.   In your problem, do the values always occur in the same order?  What if the right hand one contained `[1,1,2,3,1,5]`?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn elements after certain amount of `True`s to zero with:

```
mask[mask.cumsum() > 5] = False
#                    ^ length of the second array
```

---

```
import numpy as np
mask = np.isin([1,2,3,4,5,8,6,1,1],[1,2,3,5,1])

mask[mask.cumsum() > 5] = False
mask
# array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is the answer to my question but not to my problem.I`ve edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: It's not easy to vectorize what you are asking for in numpy (not something I can think of in a few minutes); You probably need to write loops for that.

Comment: I guess you are right, it needs 2 loops, I just looking for more optimize variant

Comment: If you are looking for speed, you can check out [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/).